# why if (isset($_POST['accept'])) not working?

Tags: php, html

i have  small problem and i don't see any mistakes in my code and server also don't returns any errors but clouse if (isset($_POST['accept'])) doesn't recognize that button was clicked.And is it some way to get value of button id?Please Help.

```
            include '../../config.php';

            db_connect();

            $zapytanie = "SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY message_id DESC";

            $r = mysql_query ($zapytanie) or die(mysql_error());

            $war="L".$_SESSION['lekarz_id'];
            echo $war;

            if (isset($_POST['accept']))
            {   
            echo "something";   
            }
            else{
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($r))
            {

            if($war == $row['message_recipient'] AND !$row['message_title']=='LP' ){
            echo $war;

            print "<table border=2 width=98% align=center>
            <tr><td><font size=1><p align=left>Od: {$row['message_recipient']}</td> <td><p align=right>Wysłana: {$row['date_of_posting']}</align></font></td></tr>
            <tr><td><p align=left><font size=1>Do:{$row['message_sender']}</td><td><b><p align=right>Temat:{$row['message_title']}</align></b></td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan=2><br  /> {$row['message_text']}</align></font></td></tr>
            </table><hr  />";
            }

            else if($war == $row['message_recipient'] AND $row['message_title']=='LP'){

                echo "
                <form>
                <table border=2 width=80%>
                <tr>
                <td>Od:Wysłana: {$row['date_of_posting']}</td>
                <td><p align=center>Wysłana: {$row['date_of_posting']}</align></font></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td><p align=center><font size=5>Do:{$row['message_sender']}</td><td><b><p align=right>Temat:{$row['message_title']}</align></b>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td ><br  /> <font size=5>{$row['message_text']}</align></font>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>";
                $id = $row['message_sender'];
                $id=substr($id, -1);

                print'
                <td>
                <form action="messages.php"  method="post">
                <input type="submit" name="accept" value="accept" id=.{$id}./>
                </form>
                </td>
                <td> </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                </form><hr  />
                ';



            }
            }
            db_close($db);
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: Why do you have a `form` inside another `form`? This may be the cause.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't explicitly set the form action to POST. As a result your form values willbe sent via GET.

Change:

```
<form>
```

to

```
<form method="POST">
```

Or look for for your value in the `$_GET` superglobal.

```
if (isset($_GET['accept']))
```

You also have a form embedded within a second form. Removing the outer form would also solve your problem.

Comment: The form tag reads `<form action="messages.php"  method="post">`

Comment: Actually there's a form embedded within a form?!

Comment: That's the true problem, the embedded form is cannibalized by the first `<form>`

Answer (score 0):

Check for `$_REQUEST['accept']`. This combines `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE`. It will contain the form value regardless of submission method.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Answer (score 0):

I also have to mention, that it's not a good idea to use submit button value to send parameter. What if you need to write "Accept" instead of "accept" on your button?

`if ($_POST['accept']=='accept')` will fail for such button. Better practice is to use hidden field with `name="accept"` (`<input type="hidden" name="accept" value="any_value" />`) and let submit button to do what it has to do - to submit form.

Also it makes your form reusable

**[phpfidle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/a2b-wvw)**